# Can we run android vm on google compute engine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I installed androidx86-4.4-rc2 in virtual box on my macos yosemite system, and I fowllow this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#import_a_virtualbox_image) upload my image to gce, but when i run this command

```
~/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud compute images create vbox-ubuntu --source-uri gs://BUCKET_NAME/vbox-image.tar.gz
```

the gce tell me 'The tar archive is not a valid image'.

So, can we run android vm on google compute engine?

Ravello Systems can run android vm on gce , how did it? thank you!